# MySQL: Access Denied for user@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I'm a New to mysql.

I was trying to set password to 'root' account. Till then i had no problem with phpmyadmin. after setting the password i'm unable to access to db neither via phpmyadmin nor a new mysql console.

Luckly, i still had the same Mysql console open through which i set my root password. So removed the root password through the same Mysql console. it was successful. But still i'm unable to login via phpmyadmin. I get error as "#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)".

But Logging-in via new mysql console is successful. Kind help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set auth_type in phpmyadmin. (via config.inc.php)

ref: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types

I recommand :

```
auth_type = 'http'
```

Comment: I got it resolved just by restarting all the services of WAMP server. Thanks for your support.